# Capacitor Push Notifications

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

Hey guys I'm trying to add Push Notifications on my project but I can't get the Device Token. I also noticed that when I changed the **AppDelegate.swift** file, XCode is giving me a deprecation warning. Could that be related?

The warnings are:

> 'InstanceID' is deprecated: FIRInstanceID is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for installation identifier handling and FIRMessaging for FCM registration token handling.

> 'instanceID(handler:)' is deprecated: Use `Installations.installationID(completion:)` to get the app instance identifier instead. Use `Messaging.token(completion:)` to get FCM registration token instead.

Any help?

Thanks